# Eclipse for PHP and Eclipse or Java messing each other up?

Tags: java, php, eclipse

When I open my Eclipse for Java, the PHP Eclipse gets opened up :)
Is this a common issue that people have?  If so, how do I go about resolving that to open the type of Eclipse I actually need?

Comment: I gave it up long ago :D I use separate installations of eclipse for every language I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm working with two eclipse installation. For the PHP installation I renamed the eclipse.exe into eclipse_php.exe and eclipse_java.exe for the Java installation. Then I created a Link on the Windows Desktop for both applications. This way I know always which one I'm starting.

Comment: This is, what I meant with the questions' comment, but without ".exe" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into programs such as [Yoxos](http://eclipsesource.com/en/yoxos/) or [Pulse](http://www.poweredbypulse.com/pulse_products.php). They allow you to have several profiles, each containing different setups. But all common plugins will be shared. This way you will have two distinctly different Eclipse installations, but everything that is in common between them will just be downloaded once.